# Negative Denominator Makes GMP crash?

Tags: c++, gmp

```
#include <gmpxx.h>

int main() {
    mpq_class a("1/-2");
    mpq_class b("1/-3");
    mpq_class c = a + b;
    printf("%s\n", c.get_str().c_str());
}
```

According to GMP's Manual, when invalid representation string is passed to the constructor, an exception is supposed to raise. However GMP doesn't in this case.

Moreover, try the code below, which leads to Segfault:

```
#include <gmpxx.h>

class Container {
    public:
        mpq_class rat;
        Container(mpq_class _rat) : rat(_rat) {}
};

int main() {
    mpq_class a("1/-3");
    Container *c = new Container(a);
}
```

Is it a bug? GMP is so well-known that I couldn't believe that it crashes so easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the manual, the section on the C++ interface for rationals starts:

> In all the following constructors, if a fraction is given then it should be in canonical form, or if not then `mpq_class::canonicalize' called.

That means that if you pass in a fraction that can be parsed, but is not in canonical form, then *you* must call `canonicalize` on it.

> If the string is not a valid rational, an `std::invalid_argument' exception is thrown.

refers to the case that the string could not be parsed at all.

Arguably, the documentation could be clearer on that.

Comment: So how do I know if a string is valid? You mean I have to do the checking by myself?

Comment: If you don't know for sure that the string is in canonical form, call `canonicalize`. That doesn't cost much in addition to the parsing. If you do anything with a rational not in canonical form, bad things may happen - if the denominator is negative, GMP may try to allocate negative-sized arrays or such.